# Что означает строка [JsonProperty("name")]? C#

Tags: c#

Что из себя представляют строки подобные такой [JsonProperty("name")]? Что за квадратные скобки? Что это за сущность?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace DummyDB
{
    public class SchemeColumn
    {

        [JsonProperty("name")]

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]

        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это зовется "Атрибутом", в данном случае это атрибут [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) библиотеки Newtonsoft.Json, который позволяет связать свойство в JSON файле со свойством в классе, если у них отличаются имена. Условно `{"SomeValue" : 123 }` и свойство `[JsonProperty("SomeValue")] public int MySuperValue {get;set;}`, как видите имена отличаются, но десериализатор их объединит, ибо стоит атрибут. Касательно класса из вопроса - атрибуты тут вовсе не нужны, ибо JSON.NET по умолчанию не смотрит на регистр.

Comment: Спасибо большое!